# How can I share variables among different load-balanced WebSphere instances?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, websphere-ce

I have web application deployed on WebSphere Community edition (WAS CE) server on four different machines for load balancing purposes.  I want to store some constant variables/objects among the four servers. If I change the variable in web application on one server, the same copy should be available for the web apps on the other three servers. Since these variables/objects are not related to the user session, sticky-session will not help here. Is JNDI the best solution? kindly share your knowledge on any other better solutions/techniques.

OS: Linux
Application Server: WebSphere Community edition (WAS CE).

Comment: I disagree with the vote to close. This isn't a ServerFault question, as the question has more to do with JavaEE in general than with WAS CE in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these values **don't** change during runtime, then placing those variables in the `ServletContext` scope would make most sense.

If these values **do** change during runtime, then they will have to reside in a storage medium that is accessible by all servers in your cluster. I'm not sure that JNDI would work for you though (I can't recall anything from the JEE spec mandating synchronization of JNDI trees across containers); distributed cache frameworks such as [EHCache](http://ehcache.org/) would make more sense.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The EHCache/Haselcast resloved my problem. These are really good frameworks for the highly distributed environment.